# My PhD Supervisor is founding a startup based on my thesis work and wants me to be first hire. Unsure if want to join

Tags: advisor, job-search, industry

I'm a current PhD student and PhD supervisor is in the process of making a startup company largely based on the devices that I've developed during my PhD thesis. My supervisor is trying hard to convince me, but not pressuring me, to join the company as its first hire. If I accept I will almost immediately begin writing my thesis to graduate early as I begin to work at the company.

I will make a modest salary to begin with (A 10K-15K increase in my PhD salary, but probably 30K-40K less than I could expect to make if I was hired at a larger company) and get roughly 2% equity. He is looking for me to commit for a year to 2 years to begin with, at which point he thinks we can bring the company to a roughly 20M valuation if successful.

I enjoy the work I do and have a relatively okay relationship with my advisor, but am beginning to get some fatigue and am interested in getting the opportunity to work on something new. At the startup I would essentially be doing the same work I'm doing now and continue working in the same labs and using the same equipment. This makes it difficult for me to get 100% excited about the opportunity because there is not really an immediately tangible change or benefit that feels like career progression other than the small increase in pay, and potential future payout if the company is successful.

I don't want to accept the offer and within my first few weeks feel like I'm already burnt out on the project. But I also don't want to pass on the offer, find my new job not as exciting (or not be able to find a job at all) and wish I would have accepted the offer. Does anybody have any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm. Get an ownership share. Maybe 30%.

Comment: Fully agree with @Buffy - 2% is absolute peanuts. Your advisor needs you, and you should be worth a founder's share. But, what do you think of the prospects of the company? Would somebody actually buy it in a few years? And, the normal advice for startups is to be paid at a normal rate, no discount for equity since it is all a crap shoot anyways.

Comment: What your advisor thinks the company will be valued at is completely irrelevant to how you are getting compensated. I think you are getting lowballed hard in exchange of practically signing away your founding work: a lose/lose for you

Comment: Has your advisor started a company before? If not they may have absolutely no idea what to compensate you, so don't be afraid to push back.

Comment: I'm not sure how people feel able to comment on what percentage of the company OP deserves, given the very limited information presented here. Perhaps better advice would be that the OP should consider consulting with a lawyer or similar professional with experience in startups and IP issues.

Comment: Also, you might like to bear in mind that there may be middle ground between 'working for startup full-time' and 'no involvement' -- for example, by being on an 'advisory board' or similar, or working on a consultancy basis. Of course you will have to consider whether that is feasible (including the potential for conflict with whatever 'main' job you end up getting), but if your advisor is keen to have your input they will probably be open to ideas.

Comment: I think it is very different depending on the country. In general, I guess accepting it might be of high value for your CV. Moreover, it is something bound on personal character. I myself I have a kind of commitment sense. But really successful people are always actively looking for different positions. I knew of cases building up possible basically fictitious future moves just to get better funding and labs. You can accept and look around. And the supervisor might also understand and still support you. You won't leave the start up out of black, most likely. Not sure it is really an answer...

Comment: @avid given the context OP has given us it seems pretty unethical for the *adviser* to start a company based upon *their* work.

Comment: What country? In the US, the Bayh-Dole Act entitles your university to partial ownership of the IP rights in the invention embodied in your idea if the work was federally funded. I would want to know if your advisor has considered this fact (though threatening to out them if not is extortion in some jurisdictions, so don't even hint at that, and it's the university's choice to forgo the rights if uni doesn't want to exploit the rights), but I wouldn't want to be part owner of a place that's conspired to hide such a fact from the feds!

Answer (score 1):

You may find you are an initial ideas person, not someone who enjoys taking an idea through into practice and commercial success. If so, you need to think in terms of getting money for your ideas, rather than for your follow-through work.

Depending on what contracts you have signed and other legalities, it may be too late to get money from your current idea, but look into it. If the devices are not patented, see if they should be, with you as an inventor. Depending on how much he contributed, your supervisor may also be an inventor.

Your objective should be to be compensated for allowing the new company to use your prior work, for example by granting you equity in exchange for a license. Most start-ups fail, so your equity needs to be high enough to allow for that. The net present value of a company that would be worth 20M in a few years if successful may be 2M, assuming 10% probability of success. 2%, even ignoring the job issue, is not enough if the technical basis depends on your thesis work.

Being underpaid by 30K for at least two years would cost you 60K, and it does not sound like you would take the job for fun. Committing to 2 years should result in higher pay to compensate for loss of flexibility. In any case, negotiate separately on permission to use your devices, and pay/benefits for any job offer.

Comment: -1 It would be highly unlikely that a PhD student would own any rights to their thesis work.  But I agree the compensation should be higher.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist That is why I wrote "Depending on what contracts you have signed and other legalities".